# SQL query to get "calculated" column is_admin for users, employees, companies

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **users**, **companies** and **employees** table. I need to query all companies, and in a computed column, show if `user_id=1` `is_employee` and then on another column if `user_id=1` `is_admin`. It should be so simple but for the life of me, I cannot figure it out.

- **users**: `user_id`
- **employees**: `user_id`, `company_id`, `is_admin`
- **companies**: `company_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem, you need to get three columns `user_id`, `is_admin` and `is_employee`. You can use `CASE` statement as follows:

I assumed that your `is_admin` is a `boolean` type and `user_id` is your primary/foreign key column on your tables related with the search.

```sql
      SELECT company_id, 
             CASE WHEN employees.user_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0
              END AS is_employee, 
             CASE WHEN employees.is_admin IS TRUE
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 
              END AS is_admin
        FROM companies
  INNER JOIN employees
          ON (companies.company_id=employees.company_id)
```

With the information provided, I believe this will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this! Although its not exactly what I needed, it definitely got me 90% there. Brilliant. For everyone else wondering, the proper SQL query I ended up using is this:

```SELECT DISTINCT companies.id, companies.name, employees.user_id,
CASE WHEN employees.user_id = 1
THEN true
ELSE false
END AS is_employee, 
CASE WHEN employees.is_admin IS TRUE
THEN true
ELSE false
END AS is_admin
FROM companies
INNER JOIN employees
ON (companies.id=employees.company_id)
WHERE employees.user_id = 1```